# Necessary components for PGP

Tags: encryption, pgp

I came across this question during an interview. I was asked: What are the two main components of PGP encryption necessary for it to work?

I was thinking in line of Private and Public Keys but I am not sure. Googling the question did not help neither.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without knowing what your interviewer had in mind, we'd be guessing. PGP requires more than just "2 things".

Comment: If we want to go as generic as possible, I'd say symmetric and asymmetric encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with having a look on what [RFC 4880, OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-1) considers important in the introduction (highlighting added by me):

> This document provides information on the message-exchange packet
> formats used by OpenPGP to provide **encryption**, **decryption**, **signing**,
> and **key management** functions.

What do we need for the individual tasks? Key management definitely requires [**public key (asymmetric) cryptography**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) for a reasonable key exchange, also signing requires it. On the other hand, encrypting and decrypting (large amounts of) data would be very slow with these algorithms, thus OpenPGP adds [**symmetric cryptography**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) for them. This is why OpenPGP is called an [hybrid cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

I'd consider (the combination of) those to be the two most fundamental concepts behind OpenPGP. Private and public keys only both belong to the concept of public key cryptography, I wouldn't count them twice.